# RSA decryption in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

How to decrypt encrypted data using RSA algorithm in iOS. I am referring [RSA Encryption in iOS](http://jslim.net/blog/2013/01/05/rsa-encryption-in-ios-and-decrypt-it-using-php/)  this but it's only for encryption I need way to implement decryption process of this. Thank you

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222524/rsa-implementations-in-objective-c

Comment: @NiteshMeshram I wrote a blog about decryption, http://jslim.net/blog/2013/06/24/rsa-decryption-on-ios/